# Obtener objeto por su id usando aggregate Mongodb

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo 2 colecciones:

1. Peliculas
2. Actores

Estoy usando `aggregate` para encontrar las películas en las que un actor participa, de la siguiente forma:

```js
peliculaCtrl.peliculasActor = async (req,res) => {
  const peliculaActor = await Actores.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: 
        {
          from: "peliculas",
          localField: "name",
          foreignField: "cast",
          as: "peliculas"
        }
    }
  ]);
  res.json(peliculaActor);
}
```

Esto funciona, pero si un actor no tiene películas también lo trae en el resultado.

Necesito hacer algo como esto, para que sólo me traiga el resultado por el `id` del objeto.

```js
peliculaCtrl.peliculasActor = async(req,res) =>{
  const peliculaActor = await Actores.findById(req.params.id).aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "peliculas",
          localField: "name",
          foreignField: "cast",
          as: "peliculas"
        }
    }
  ]);
  res.json(peliculaActor);
}
```

Pero obtengo:

> TypeError: Actores.findById(...).aggregate is not a function

Todo esto es necesario para obtener Maestro-Detalle usando ActivateRoute en Angular.

Espero su ayuda amigos.

Comment: Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de explicarme bien mis dudas, me queda claro el proceso y he logrado pedir esta ruta [http://localhost:3000/api/peliculas/actores/reparto/5dc0365e0b2c0c479cb3fba3]  y obtener el actor con sus peliculas.  Se supone que con esto al pedir esta ruta desde angular me funcionaria ActivatedRoute pero al darle clic me toma el id pero no me trae los datos asociados al actor. Cuando uso `Actores.findById(req.params.id);` me funcionan ActivatedRoute de Angular no se si tendria que hacer otra pregunta al respecto pero espero me puedas entender.

Answer (score 1):

El resultado es correcto en teoría: si listas los actores y sus películas, algunos no tienen películas, pero tú querías listar actores y eso obtuviste.

```
   [{
    "actor": "Marlon Brando",
    "películas": [...muchas...]
   },
   {
    "actor": "Pedrito",
    "películas": []
   }]
```

Tú querías que Pedrito no apareciera.

Veamos un ejemplo simple:

## Una sola colección (Películas):

un ejemplo muy básico sería una colección de películas del tipo:

```js
const collection = [
  {
    "title": "The Avengers",
    "year": 2012,
    "cast": [
      "Robert Downey Jr.",
      "Chris Evans",
      "Mark Ruffalo",
      "Tom Hiddleston",
      "Chris Hemsworth"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Thor: Ragnarok",
    "year": 2017,
    "cast": [
      "Chris Hemsworth",
      "Tom Hiddleston",
      "Mark Ruffalo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Captain America: Civil War",
    "year": 2016,
    "cast": [
      "Scarlett Johansson",
      "Tom Holland",
      "Chris Evans",
      "Robert Downey Jr."
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Avengers: Age of Ultron",
    "year": 2015,
    "cast": [
      "Scarlett Johansson",
      "Robert Downey Jr.",
      "Chris Evans",
      "Chris Hemsworth",
      "Mark Ruffalo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Avengers: Infinity War",
    "year": 2018,
    "cast": [
      "Robert Downey Jr.",
      "Chris Hemsworth",
      "Mark Ruffalo",
      "Chris Evans",
      "Scarlett Johansson",
      "Tom Holland",
      "Tom Hiddleston",
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Iron Man 3",
    "year": 2013,
    "cast": [
      "Robert Downey Jr.",
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Spider-Man: Homecoming",
    "year": 2017,
    "cast": [
      "Scarlett Johansson",
      "Tom Holland",
      "Robert Downey Jr."
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Thor",
    "year": 2011,
    "cast": [
      "Chris Hemsworth",
      "Tom Hiddleston",
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Thor: The Dark World",
    "year": 2013,
    "cast": [
      "Chris Hemsworth",
      "Tom Hiddleston"
    ]
  }
]
```

Tú podrías obtener en qué películas salió cada actor haciendo:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$cast" },
  { $group: {
      _id: "$cast",
      movies: {
        $push: "$title"
      }
  }} 
])
```

Lo cual en este caso daría lugar a objetos como

```js
  [ {
    "_id": "Robert Downey Jr.",
    "movies": [
      "The Avengers",
      "Captain America: Civil War",
      "Avengers: Age of Ultron",
      "Avengers: Infinity War",
      "Iron Man 3",
      "Spider-Man: Homecoming"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "Chris Evans",
    "movies": [
      "The Avengers",
      "Captain America: Civil War",
      "Avengers: Age of Ultron",
      "Avengers: Infinity War"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "Mark Ruffalo",
    "movies": [
      "The Avengers",
      "Thor: Ragnarok",
      "Avengers: Age of Ultron",
      "Avengers: Infinity War"
    ]
  }]
```

Si tú quisieras buscar en particular películas donde sale Robert Downey Junior aplicas un filtro al final de la cola de agregación:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$cast" },
  { $group: {
      _id: "$cast",
      movies: {
        $push: "$title"
      }
  }},
  {$match: {
  _id: "Robert Downey Jr."
  }}
])
```

[Ver fiddle de ejemplo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y7xvSXmz58t)

Este ejemplo es muy básico porque terminas con el nombre del actor como id, y no creo que te baste con eso.

## Dos Colecciones (Actors y Movies)

Tú pareces querer obtener la colección de actores enriqueciéndola con un array de películas, por lo que tenemos que obtener el id del actor en el resultado. Algo como:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"), // id del actor
"actor": "Chris Hemsworth",
"peliculas": [
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000008"), // id de la película
    "title": "The Avengers"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000009"),
    "title": "Thor: Ragnarok"
  }]
 }
```

O incluso más simple:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"), // id del actor
"actor": "Chris Hemsworth",
"peliculas": [
   "The Avengers",
    "Thor: Ragnarok"
 ]
}
```

Pensemos entonces que tienes dos colecciones. La de películas es la misma, y en la colección de actores tienes uno que no aparece en ninguna película (Pedrito). Ese tal Pedrito no tiene que estar en el resultado final.

```
actors: [
  {"name": "Pedrito"},
  {"name": "Chris Evans"},
  {"name": "Chris Hemsworth"},
  {"name": "Mark Ruffalo"},
  {"name": "Robert Downey Jr."},
  {"name": "Scarlett Johansson"},
  {"name": "Tom Hiddleston"},
  {"name": "Tom Holland" }
]
```

```js
db={
  actors: [
    {
      "name": "Pedrito"
    },
    {
      "name": "Chris Evans"
    },
    {
      "name": "Chris Hemsworth"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mark Ruffalo"
    },
    {
      "name": "Robert Downey Jr."
    },
    {
      "name": "Scarlett Johansson"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tom Hiddleston"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tom Holland"
    }
  ],
  movies: [
    {
      "title": "The Avengers",
      "year": 2012,
      "cast": [
        "Robert Downey Jr.",
        "Chris Evans",
        "Mark Ruffalo",
        "Tom Hiddleston",
        "Chris Hemsworth"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Thor: Ragnarok",
      "year": 2017,
      "cast": [
        "Chris Hemsworth",
        "Tom Hiddleston",
        "Mark Ruffalo"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Captain America: Civil War",
      "year": 2016,
      "cast": [
        "Scarlett Johansson",
        "Tom Holland",
        "Chris Evans",
        "Robert Downey Jr."
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Avengers: Age of Ultron",
      "year": 2015,
      "cast": [
        "Scarlett Johansson",
        "Robert Downey Jr.",
        "Chris Evans",
        "Chris Hemsworth",
        "Mark Ruffalo"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Avengers: Infinity War",
      "year": 2018,
      "cast": [
        "Robert Downey Jr.",
        "Chris Hemsworth",
        "Mark Ruffalo",
        "Chris Evans",
        "Scarlett Johansson",
        "Tom Holland",
        "Tom Hiddleston",
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Iron Man 3",
      "year": 2013,
      "cast": [
        "Robert Downey Jr.",
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Spider-Man: Homecoming",
      "year": 2017,
      "cast": [
        "Scarlett Johansson",
        "Tom Holland",
        "Robert Downey Jr."
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Thor",
      "year": 2011,
      "cast": [
        "Chris Hemsworth",
        "Tom Hiddleston",
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Thor: The Dark World",
      "year": 2013,
      "cast": [
        "Chris Hemsworth",
        "Tom Hiddleston"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Igual que en el primer ejemplo, es necesario operar sobre las películas dado que el campo `cast` es un array y necesitas hacer $unwind para que calce con algún actor. Esto equivale a decir que

```
db.movies.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$cast"
  }
])
```

Con eso, por cada actor de cada película se genera un documento (con el id de la película)

```js
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000008"),
    "cast": "Robert Downey Jr.",
    "title": "The Avengers",
    "year": 2012
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000008"),
    "cast": "Chris Evans",
    "title": "The Avengers",
    "year": 2012
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000008"),
    "cast": "Mark Ruffalo",
    "title": "The Avengers",
    "year": 2012
  },
```

Ahora puedes añadir la etapa del $lookup:

```
{
 $lookup: {
  from: "actors",
  localField: "cast",
  foreignField: "name",
  as: "actores"
 }
}
```

Pero ese operador, si bien te dice qué documento de la colección `actors` calza con un miembro del cast, ese documento viene en un array y todavía no puedes acceder directamente a sus id. (nótese que Pedrito ya no está en ningún arreglo).

```js
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000008"),
    "actores": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000004"),
        "name": "Robert Downey Jr."
      }
    ],
    "cast": "Robert Downey Jr.",
    "title": "The Avengers",
    "year": 2012
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000008"),
    "actores": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
        "name": "Chris Evans"
      }
    ],
    "cast": "Chris Evans",
    "title": "The Avengers",
    "year": 2012
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000008"),
    "actores": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
        "name": "Mark Ruffalo"
      }
    ],
    "cast": "Mark Ruffalo",
    "title": "The Avengers",
    "year": 2012
  },
```

Añades la agrupación para que ahora mande el actor (con su id) y las películas en cambio sean un array hijo de cada actor:

```
{
    $group: {
      _id: "$actores._id",
      actor: {
        $first: "$cast"
      },
      peliculas: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$_id",
          title: "$title"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

El resultado tiene el id del actor, pero en un array.

```js
  

{
    "_id": [
      ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000005")
    ],
    "actor": "Scarlett Johansson",
    "peliculas": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000a"),
        "title": "Captain America: Civil War"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000b"),
        "title": "Avengers: Age of Ultron"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000c"),
        "title": "Avengers: Infinity War"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000e"),
        "title": "Spider-Man: Homecoming"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": [
      ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003")
    ],
    "actor": "Mark Ruffalo",
    "peliculas": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000008"),
        "title": "The Avengers"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000009"),
        "title": "Thor: Ragnarok"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000b"),
        "title": "Avengers: Age of Ultron"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000c"),
        "title": "Avengers: Infinity War"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Así que en el último paso vuelves a hacer un unwind. El pipeline de agrupación queda:

```
db.movies.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$cast"  },
  { $lookup: {
      from: "actors",
      localField: "cast",
      foreignField: "name",
      as: "actores"    }  },
  { $group: {
      _id: "$actores._id",
      actor: {$first: "$cast"},
      peliculas: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$_id",
          title: "$title"
        }
    }}},
  { $unwind: "$_id" } // sólo para obtener el id del actor limpio
])
```

Y el resultado son documentos con la forma:

```
 {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"), // id del actor
    "actor": "Chris Hemsworth",
    "peliculas": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000008"), // id de la película
        "title": "The Avengers"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000009"),
        "title": "Thor: Ragnarok"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000b"),
        "title": "Avengers: Age of Ultron"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000c"),
        "title": "Avengers: Infinity War"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000f"),
        "title": "Thor"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000010"),
        "title": "Thor: The Dark World"
      }
    ]
  },
```

```js
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "actor": "Chris Hemsworth",
    "peliculas": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000008"),
        "title": "The Avengers"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000009"),
        "title": "Thor: Ragnarok"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000b"),
        "title": "Avengers: Age of Ultron"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000c"),
        "title": "Avengers: Infinity War"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000f"),
        "title": "Thor"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000010"),
        "title": "Thor: The Dark World"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "actor": "Mark Ruffalo",
    "peliculas": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000008"),
        "title": "The Avengers"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000009"),
        "title": "Thor: Ragnarok"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000b"),
        "title": "Avengers: Age of Ultron"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000c"),
        "title": "Avengers: Infinity War"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000007"),
    "actor": "Tom Holland",
    "peliculas": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000a"),
        "title": "Captain America: Civil War"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000c"),
        "title": "Avengers: Infinity War"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000e"),
        "title": "Spider-Man: Homecoming"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000006"),
    "actor": "Tom Hiddleston",
    "peliculas": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000008"),
        "title": "The Avengers"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000009"),
        "title": "Thor: Ragnarok"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000c"),
        "title": "Avengers: Infinity War"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000f"),
        "title": "Thor"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000010"),
        "title": "Thor: The Dark World"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "actor": "Chris Evans",
    "peliculas": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000008"),
        "title": "The Avengers"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000a"),
        "title": "Captain America: Civil War"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000b"),
        "title": "Avengers: Age of Ultron"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000c"),
        "title": "Avengers: Infinity War"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000004"),
    "actor": "Robert Downey Jr.",
    "peliculas": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000008"),
        "title": "The Avengers"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000a"),
        "title": "Captain America: Civil War"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000b"),
        "title": "Avengers: Age of Ultron"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000c"),
        "title": "Avengers: Infinity War"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000d"),
        "title": "Iron Man 3"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000e"),
        "title": "Spider-Man: Homecoming"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000005"),
    "actor": "Scarlett Johansson",
    "peliculas": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000a"),
        "title": "Captain America: Civil War"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000b"),
        "title": "Avengers: Age of Ultron"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000c"),
        "title": "Avengers: Infinity War"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e00010203040500000e"),
        "title": "Spider-Man: Homecoming"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Ver fiddle de ejemplo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OnaexBzu7FJ)

Si no te interesa el id de la película, el stage de agrupación podría ser, en cambio:

```
{
    $group: {
      _id: "$actores._id",
      actor: {
        $first: "$cast"
      },
      peliculas: {
        $push: "$title"
      }
    }
  },
```

Y el resultado final (después del último $unwind) tendría el formato:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000005"),
    "actor": "Scarlett Johansson",
    "peliculas": [
      "Captain America: Civil War",
      "Avengers: Age of Ultron",
      "Avengers: Infinity War",
      "Spider-Man: Homecoming"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de explicarme bien mis dudas, me queda claro el proceso y he logrado pedir esta ruta [http://localhost:3000/api/peliculas/actores/reparto/5dc0365e0b2c0c479cb3fba3]  y obtener el actor con sus peliculas.  Se supoe que con esto al pedit esta ruta desde angular me funcionaria ActivatedRoute pero al darle clic me toma el id pero no me trae los datos asociados al actor. Cuando uso `Actores.findById(req.params.id);` me funcionan ActivatedRoute de Angular no se si tendria que hacer otra pregunta al respecto pero espero me puedas entender.

Answer (score 1):

Debido a que no aportas un ejemplo claro del tipo de documentos involucrados, voy a hacer unas suposiciones básicas.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea realizar una consulta a una colección (*Actores*), de tal forma que la misma devuelva un documento con el nombre, y una lista de las películas en las que ha participado. La consulta se realizará por medio el ID del documento. Si el documento (*actor*) no tiene películas asociadas, la consulta no devolverá resultados.

La consulta se realizará a una base de datos MongoDB, usando el ODM [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/).

**SOLUCIÓN**

La respuesta dada por @amenadiel, aparte de ser excelente, expone detalles sobre algunas formas de organizar tus colecciones, para que mediante procesos de agregación se puedan extraer los datos necesarios.

Su respuesta se enfoca en resolver el problema de extraer sólo los documentos de la colección *Actores* que tengan una referencia directa con uno o varios documentos de la colección *Películas*. Dejando por fuera los actores que no hayan participado en ninguna película de la colección de películas.

Mi respuesta se basará en tu pregunta sobre el uso de Mongoose y cómo realizar la consulta usando el ID de un documento de la colección de actores.

En tu pregunta dices que necesitas traer los resultados de un sólo actor:

> *para que sólo me traiga el resultado por el id del objeto:*
>
> `Actores.findById(...)`

Resulta que una [`query`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html) y un [`aggregate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html) de Mongoose son métodos totalmente distintos y no son intercambiables. Es decir, no puedes ejecutar una sobre el resultado de otra. Es por ello que falla lo que intentas hacer:

```
// esto falla
const peliculaActor = await Actores.findById(req.params.id).aggregate([ ... ]);
```

Para filtrar un (o varios) documento usando un proceso de agregación, debes usar una etapa [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/).

Suponiendo que la estructura de tus documentos es parecida a la siguiente:
(Tomado de la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/309275/obtener-objeto-por-su-id-usando-aggregate-mongodb/309366#309366) de @amenadiel).

**Actores**

```
actoresSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nombre: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
```

**Peliculas**

```
const peliculaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  year: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  cast: {
    type: Array,
    default: [];
  }
});
```

**Etapas**

Las etapas a ser usadas serán las siguientes:

**[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)**

Usaremos esta etapa para buscar sólo documentos con el campo `_id` provisto.

```
{ 
  $match: { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) }
}
```

El resultado debería verse parecido a lo siguiente:

```
[ { _id: 5dd50f77cbd9ee7c5dea5067, name: 'Pedrito' } ]
```

**[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)**

Usaremos esta etapa para buscar en la colección de películas según el campo local `name`.

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "peliculas",
    localField: "name",
    foreignField: "cast",
    as: "peliculas"
  }
}
```

El resultado podría verse así en caso que un actor no participase en ninguna película de la colección películas:

```
[ { _id: 5dd50f77cbd9ee7c5dea5067, name: 'Pedrito', peliculas: [] } ]
```

Si el actor en cambio, si que ha participado en alguna película, el resultado podría verse de la siguiente forma:

```
[
  {
    _id: 5dd50f77cbd9ee7c5dea506a,
    name: 'Mark Ruffalo',
    peliculas: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] // <- cada documento traído de la colección peliculas donde participa el actor
  }
]
```

**[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)**

Usaremos esta etapa para separar en varios documentos según los datos devueltos por `$lookup`.

```js
{
  $unwind: "$peliculas"
}
```

En esta etapa, si el `array` de películas está vacío (caso Pedrito), entonces `$unwind` ignorará por defecto el documento de entrada, por lo tanto no habrá salida. Esto quiere decir, que no se devolverá ningún documento en el `array` de salida. Siendo consecuentes con la premisa de no devolver un actor si el mismo no ha participado en ninguna película de mi colección.

En cambio, si el actor efectivamente a participado en alguna película, el resultado mostrado será parecido al siguiente:

```js
[
  {
    _id: 5dd50f77cbd9ee7c5dea506a,
    name: 'Mark Ruffalo',
    peliculas: {
      _id: 5dd50f77cbd9ee7c5dea506f,
      title: 'The Avengers',
      year: 2012,
      cast: [Array]
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 5dd50f77cbd9ee7c5dea506a,
    name: 'Mark Ruffalo',
    peliculas: {
      _id: 5dd50f77cbd9ee7c5dea5070,
      title: 'Thor: Ragnarok',
      year: 2017,
      cast: [Array]
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 5dd50f77cbd9ee7c5dea506a,
    name: 'Mark Ruffalo',
    peliculas: {
      _id: 5dd50f77cbd9ee7c5dea5072,
      title: 'Avengers: Age of Ultron',
      year: 2015,
      cast: [Array]
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 5dd50f77cbd9ee7c5dea506a,
    name: 'Mark Ruffalo',
    peliculas: {
      _id: 5dd50f77cbd9ee7c5dea5073,
      title: 'Avengers: Infinity War',
      year: 2018,
      cast: [Array]
    }
  }
]
```

**[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)**

Usaremos esta etapa para extraer los datos del campo `peliculas` y llevarlos al documento raíz, para ello usaremos un proceso de [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/#exp._S_mergeObjects) para mezclar los campos del documento raíz ([`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html#replaceroot-with-a-new-document-created-from-root-and-a-default-document)) con los campos del documento en el campo `peliculas`. Esto se hará por cada documento de la etapa anterior.

```js
{
  $replaceRoot: {
    newRoot: {
      $mergeObjects: [
        "$peliculas",
        "$$ROOT"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Una posible salida sería:

```js
[
 ...,
  {
    _id: 5dd50f77cbd9ee7c5dea506a,
    title: 'The Avengers',
    year: 2012,
    cast: [
      'Robert Downey Jr.',
      'Chris Evans',
      'Mark Ruffalo',
      'Tom Hiddleston',
      'Chris Hemsworth'
    ],
    name: 'Mark Ruffalo',
    movies: {
      _id: 5dd50f77cbd9ee7c5dea506f,
      title: 'The Avengers',
      year: 2012,
      cast: [Array]
    }
  },
...
]
```

Claramente vemos que se repiten los campos de `peliculas` en el documento raíz.

**[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)**

Usaremos esta etapa para eliminar los campos que no deseamos en nuestro documento, por ejemplo, el campo peliculas no tiene sentido ya que todos sus elementos ahora están en el documento raíz.

```js
{
  $project: {
    peliculas: 0, // indico con 0 si no deseo dicho campo
    cast: 0,
    year: 0
  }
}
```

Una posible salida sería:

```js
[
  {
    _id: 5dd50f77cbd9ee7c5dea506a,
    title: 'The Avengers',
    name: 'Mark Ruffalo'
  },
  {
    _id: 5dd50f77cbd9ee7c5dea506a,
    title: 'Thor: Ragnarok',
    name: 'Mark Ruffalo'
  },
  {
    _id: 5dd50f77cbd9ee7c5dea506a,
    title: 'Avengers: Age of Ultron',
    name: 'Mark Ruffalo'
  },
  {
    _id: 5dd50f77cbd9ee7c5dea506a,
    title: 'Avengers: Infinity War',
    name: 'Mark Ruffalo'
  }
]
```

**[`group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)**

Usaremos esta etapa para agrupar todos nuestros documentos en un único documento, usando como elemento de agrupación el campo `_id`, y como acumulador un campo llamado `peliculas` donde iremos almacenando el título de la película. Para agregar el nombre del actor usaremos el operador de acumulación [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first).

```js
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    name: {
      $first: "$name" // <- para devolver el nombre del actor
    },
    peliculas: {
      $push: "$title" // <- para crear un array con el nombre de las peliculas
    }
  }
}
```

Una posible salida sería:

```js
[
  {
    _id: 5dd50f77cbd9ee7c5dea506a,
    name: 'Mark Ruffalo',
    peliculas: [
      'The Avengers',
      'Thor: Ragnarok',
      'Avengers: Age of Ultron',
      'Avengers: Infinity War'
    ]
  }
]
```

Con esto se completa el proceso de agregación para ser usado con Mongoose sobre una base de datos MongoDB.

Tu código podría verse como:

```js
peliculaCtrl.peliculasActor = async (req, res) => {
  // Mongoose no hace cast del tipo ObjectID, por lo tanto debemos crearlo a partir del
  // valor pasado en req.params.id
  const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
  // creamos el objeto de agregación
  const agregacionActores = Actores.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) // <- aqui se hace el cast de string a ObjectID
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "peliculas",
        localField: "name",
        foreignField: "cast",
        as: "peliculas"
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$peliculas"
    },
    {
      $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: {
          $mergeObjects: [
            "$peliculas",
            "$$ROOT"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        peliculas: 0,
        cast: 0,
        year: 0
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        name: {
          $first: "$name"
        },
        peliculas: {
          $push: "$title"
        }
      }
    }
  ]);
  // cuando se trabaja con Promesas se debe usar try catch
  try {
    const peliculaActor = await agregacionActores.exec() // <- llamamos al método exec() para realizar el proceso de agregación
    res.json(peliculaActor);
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.log(error.message)
    ...
  }
}
```

Espero que esto resuelva tu duda.

Comment: Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de explicarme bien mis dudas, me queda claro el proceso y he logrado pedir esta ruta [http://localhost:3000/api/peliculas/actores/reparto/5dc0365e0b2c0c479cb3fba3]  y obtener el actor con sus peliculas.  Se supone que con esto al pedir esta ruta desde angular me funcionaria ActivatedRoute pero al darle clic me toma el id pero no me trae los datos asociados al actor. Cuando uso `Actores.findById(req.params.id);` me funcionan ActivatedRoute de Angular no se si tendria que hacer otra pregunta al respecto pero espero me puedas entender.